# access vba subtract 2 time values. If difference is positive subtract time 1 value as yesterday

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have time values that are order and deliver time and look like 8:30 AM, 9:30 AM etc

I want the difference in time value

so I do:

```
timeDiff = CInt((Me.orderTime - Me.deliveryTime) * 24)
```

For 8:00 AM and 9:30 AM it returns -1.5 which is exactly what I want.

This value should always be negative. But sometime the orderTime can be 7:30 PM yesterday and deliver time 7:30 AM today. Which will result in positive 12.

If time time is positive, I know that the orderTime is from yesterday.

I cannot do this:

```
If timeDiff > 0 Then
    timeDiff = timeDiff * -1
End If
```

Because for 7:30 PM yesterday and 8:30 AM today it will return -11 instead of -13. How can I achieve what I want in vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, If you use the Cint function, you cannot get the value below the decimal point.

```
Dim myTime As Double
Dim timeDiff As Double

myTime = Me.deliveryTime - Me.orderTime
If myTime < 0 Then
    myTime = myTime + 1
End If

timeDiff = myTime * 24
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner will do:

```vb
timeDiff = -TimeValue(CDate(Me.orderTime - Me.deliveryTime + 1)) * 24

' Examples:

timeDiff = -TimeValue(CDate(#9:30 AM# - #8:00 AM# + 1)) * 24
' -> -1.5

timeDiff = -TimeValue(CDate(#7:30 PM# - #8:30 AM# + 1)) * 24
' -> -11
```